# Resume old activity by passing new data in bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bundle

I have couple of activities say A , B, C. Activity A starts B , B starts C and so on. In my app I have put a navigation drawer which allows users to go back to activity A. When user goes back to activity A I have passed some flags which don't actually restart the activity but just resumes it.

```
intent = new Intent(activity, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Now I m trying to pass some data using bundles.

```
    bundle.putInt("selectedTab", FEATURED_COUPONS);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

But in my activity A the bundle is always null.

```
if(bundle != null)
{
    if(bundle.containsKey("selectedTab"))
    {
        int tab = bundle.getInt("selectedTab");
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code where you get the bundle and start the activity A

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're going about things in the wrong way.

If all you want to do is put an `Integer` extra into the `Intent` extras then don't do this...

```
bundle.putInt("selectedTab", FEATURED_COUPONS);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

From the docs for `putExtras(Bundle extras)`...

> Add a set of extended data to the intent. **The keys must include a package prefix**, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Instead just use...

```
intent.putExtra("selectedTab", FEATURED_COUPONS);
```

This isn't the real cause of your problem however. As Sumit Uppal mentions, you should implement [onNewIntent(Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) in `Activity` A. You can then use that to set the 'current' `Intent` to be the new `Intent`...

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null)
        setIntent(intent);
}
```

Then in `onResume()` you can use...

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

...and then get the `Bundle` from that `Intent`.

Comment: A bit late, but I stumbled this solution just now, finally ended my agony after 3 hours of searching!!!

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way to do this when you call launcher activity with ACTION_MAIN?

Comment: Please help .. I am trying to implement into my code as well by putting the Intent intent = get Intent() code in onResume() but am still not passing from one Activity to another.  Keep in mind I have 2 users at the same time on different devices but with the same app.  I am trying to pass a value from Rider to Driver but still coming out null.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do  " if(bundle != null)" task in onNewIntent(Intent) method

Comment: is onNewIntent(intent) method on the receiving app or the sending app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass data to an activity already created you must use startActivityForResult and override onActivityResult method in activity A.

Instead, if you create the activity again I recommend to use finish() in the activity, after the startActivity method.